# using "yum search" can find the rpm package but "yum install " mentions nothing to do

Tags: linux, yum

When I execute the yum search the mysql-libs like this:

```
$sudo yum search mysql-libs
Loaded plugins: branch, downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
========================================================================== N/S                 Matched: mysql-libs ==========================================================================
mysql-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MySQL clients

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

But when I execute the install command it says "nothing to do "

```
$sudo yum install mysql-libs
Loaded plugins: branch, downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
```

Does anybody ever meet the seem problem and fixed it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with rpm command,

```
# rpm -qa | grep mysql-libs
```

or you need to install repo and check it.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: thanks. when i execute "rpm -qa | grep 'mysql-libs'" i got nothing.